# How can I add custom headers to emails sent through Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add headers to emails being sent by app-engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902721/is-it-possible-to-add-headers-to-emails-being-sent-by-app-engine)

I'm using Python.
This documentation page: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html
doesn't have the answer.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902721/is-it-possible-to-add-headers-to-emails-being-sent-by-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

from looking in appengine/api/mail.py

```
mime_message = myMessage.to_mime_message()
mime_message['message_id'] = 'myid'
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out this is a duplicate question, so I've posted your answer in the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902721/is-it-possible-to-add-headers-to-emails-being-sent-by-app-engine